# Preventing SQL injection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sql-injection, node-mysql

Is it possible to prevent SQL injections in Node.js (preferably with a module) in the same way that PHP had Prepared Statements that protected against them.

If so, how? If not, **what are some examples** that might bypass the code I've provided (see below).

---

Some Context:

I'm making a web application with a back-end stack consisting of Node.js + MySql using the [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module. From a usability perspective, the module is great, but it has not yet implemented something akin to PHP's [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (though I'm aware it is on the [todo](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#todo)).

From my understanding, PHP's implementation of prepared statements, among other things, [helped greatly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602) in the prevention of SQL injections. I'm worried, though, that my node.js app may be open to similar attacks, [even with the string escaping provided by default](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) (as in the code snippet below).

node-mysql seems to be the most popular mysql connector for node.js, so I was wondering what other people might be doing (if anything) to account for this issue - or if it is even an issue with node.js to begin with (not sure how this wouldn't be, since user/client-side input is involved).

**Should I switch to [node-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native) for the time being, since it does provide prepared statements?** I'm hesitant to do this, because it does not seem to be as active as node-mysql (though that may just mean that it is complete).

Here is a snippet of user registration code, which uses the [sanitizer](https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer) module, along with node-mysql's prepared statement-like syntax (which, as I mentioned above, does character escaping), to prevent cross site scripting and sql injections, respectively:

```
// Prevent xss
var clean_user = sanitizer.sanitize(username);

// assume password is hashed already
var post = {Username: clean_user, Password: hash};

// This just uses connection.escape() underneath
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post,
   function(err, results)
   {
       // Can a Sql injection happen here?
   });
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `node-mysql` library automatically performs escaping when used as you are already doing. See https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: Caution These methods of escaping values only works when the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL mode is disabled (which is the default state for MySQL servers) => source is node-MySQL itself. 

They have preparing method as well which is much cleaner and secure.
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries

Answer (score 17):

The library has a [section](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) in the readme about escaping. It's Javascript-native, so I do not suggest switching to [node-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native). The documentation states these guidelines for escaping:

**Edit:** [node-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native) is also a pure-Javascript solution.

- Numbers are left untouched
- Booleans are converted to `true` / `false` strings
- Date objects are converted to `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` strings
- Buffers are converted to hex strings, e.g. `X'0fa5'`
- Strings are safely escaped
- Arrays are turned into list, e.g. `['a', 'b']` turns into `'a', 'b'`
- Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g. `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` turns into `('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')`
- Objects are turned into `key = 'val'` pairs. Nested objects are cast to strings.
- `undefined` / `null` are converted to `NULL`
- `NaN` / `Infinity` are left as-is. MySQL does not support these, and trying to insert them as values will trigger MySQL errors until they implement support.

This allows for you to do things like so:

```
var userId = 5;
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [userId], function(err, results) {
  //query.sql returns SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '5'
});
```

As well as this:

```
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
  //query.sql returns INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
});
```

Aside from those functions, you can also use the escape functions:

```
connection.escape(query);
mysql.escape(query);
```

To escape query identifiers:

```
mysql.escapeId(identifier);
```

And as a response to your comment on prepared statements:

> From a usability perspective, the module is great, but it has not yet implemented something akin to PHP's Prepared Statements.

The prepared statements are on the [todo](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#todo) list for this connector, but this module at least allows you to specify custom formats that can be very similar to prepared statements. Here's an example from the readme:

```
connection.config.queryFormat = function (query, values) {
  if (!values) return query;
  return query.replace(/\:(\w+)/g, function (txt, key) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return this.escape(values[key]);
    }
    return txt;
  }.bind(this));
};
```

This changes the query format of the connection so you can use queries like this:

```
connection.query("UPDATE posts SET title = :title", { title: "Hello MySQL" });
//equivalent to
connection.query("UPDATE posts SET title = " + mysql.escape("Hello MySQL");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - I'm aware of the prepared-like style. Underneath, though, the characters are being escaped. See: ["However, it really just uses the same connection.escape()"](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values). As far as not using node-mysql-native: this is what I'm struggling with. If node-mysql-native implements prepared statements and its implementations prevents SQL injections, shouldn't I make the switch until node-mysql has them?

Comment: It's sort of chicken-and-egg question. I'm not actively developing my driver because most people use @felixge's I'll probably try to find some time to port prepared statements to node-mysql as it indeed gives  some performance benefits (and potentially makes sql injections harder). Feel free to comment/post issues if you decide to give it a go

Comment: @funseiki I'm sure prepared statements would be the best solution, but I'm very sure that the escaping will prevent SQL injections. Since the module itself is supported by Joyent, the module is active and evidently thoroughly checked. If this module wasn't ready for production, then I don't think the module would have an average of 1000 downloads/day last month. Note that node-mysql-native is 6 months since it was last developed, and node-mysql is very active, with multiple people working on it.

Comment: @AndreySidorov Thanks for the comment - if I do attempt to tackle it, I'll post an update. I don't think it'll be anytime soon, though, since it doesn't seem like it'll be an easy beast to handle (will require more research than I currently have time for). Also thanks for making that driver - you guys are the reason Node.js makes it easy to get apps running quickly

Comment: @hexacyanide Because node-mysql is so popular, I was hoping I could get a response from members of the community regarding security issues they may have encountered (or prevented) as well as a convincing argument as to why the current character escape approach is secure enough for their code.

Comment: Is there a generic SQL vender neutral version that I could use in say an Ionic 3 project? (uses Angular 4 under covers)

Answer (score 12):

In regards to testing if a module you are utilizing is secure or not there are several routes you can take. I will touch on the pros/cons of each so you can make a more informed decision.

Currently, there aren't any vulnerabilities for the module you are utilizing, however, this can often lead to a false sense of security as there very well could be a vulnerability currently exploiting the module/software package you are using and you wouldn't be alerted to a problem until the vendor applies a fix/patch.

1. To keep abreast of vulnerabilities you will need to follow mailing lists, forums, IRC & other hacking related discussions.
   PRO: You can often times you will become aware of potential problems within a library before a vendor has been alerted or has issued a fix/patch to remedy the potential avenue of attack on their software.
   CON: This can be very time consuming and resource intensive. If you do go this route a bot using RSS feeds, log parsing (IRC chat logs) and or a web **scraper** using key phrases (in this case node-mysql-native) and notifications can help reduce time spent trolling these resources.
2. Create a fuzzer, use a [fuzzer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fuzzing) or other vulnerability framework such as [metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com), [sqlMap](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap) etc. to help test for problems that the vendor may not have looked for.
   PRO: This can prove to be a sure fire method of ensuring to an acceptable level whether or not the module/software you are implementing is safe for public access.
   CON: This also becomes time consuming and costly. The other problem will stem from false positives as well as uneducated review of the results where a problem resides but is not noticed.

Really security, and application security in general can be very time consuming and resource intensive. One thing managers will always use is a formula to determine the cost effectiveness (manpower, resources, time, pay etc) of performing the above two options.

Anyways, I realize this is not a 'yes' or 'no' answer that may have been hoping for but I don't think anyone can give that to you until they perform an analysis of the software in question.

Answer (score 5):

Mysql-native has been outdated so it became [MySQL2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) that is a new module created with the help of the original MySQL module's team. This module has more features and I think it has what you want as it has prepared statements(by using.execute()) like in PHP for more security.

It's also very active(the last change was from 2-1 days) I didn't try it before but I think it's what you want and more.

Answer (score 1):

**Preventing SQL injections**

**SQL injections** is a common web hacking technique to destroy or misuse your database. To prevent SQL injections, you should use escape the values when query values are variables provided by the user.

**Escape query values by using the mysql.escape() method:**

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ' + mysql.escape(adr);
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

**Escape query values by using the placeholder ? method:**

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ?';
con.query(sql, [adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

[More Detail](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp)