# Using Javascript variables in MYSQL queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I've been working on this problem for a while and can't seem to find any good info on it.

I'm running a node.js server on an EC2 instance and need to add rows to a MYSQL table with the following code:

```
client.query('SELECT curattend FROM table1 WHERE ind=1', function(err,result){
        att = result[0].curattend;
        console.log(att);

        client.query("INSERT INTO archive (attendance) VALUES ('att')", function(err,info){
                });

        console.log(att);

        });
```

I printed 'att' before and after just to be sure...att is equal to '233'. However, the number'0' keeps getting uploaded into the MYSQL table.

Can anyone point me to a resource that can help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on user2246674's constructive comments, I also learned something today.

Rather than this:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO archive (attendance) VALUES (" + att + ")"
```

Try this instead:

```
 var att  = result[0].curattend;
 client.query("INSERT INTO archive (attendance) VALUES (?);", [att], function(err,info){ });
 // This creates the insert statement INSERT INTO archive (attendance) VALUES (att);
```

Comment: Oh, yay, a whole new era of *SQL injection* (or *accidental breakage*) - surely there must be a *better* way? Because, the last thing I want is more of this junk.

Comment: Oh, yes. This has been solved years ago, and thankfully, [it's also appears solved in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js). (It may use escaping vs proper prepared statements, but the thing is: you shouldn't have to worry about passing data to SQL!)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
('"+att+"')"
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer better please?