# Does nodejs mysql module do the escaping for us? if not then how to sanitize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-injection

I'm new to Node.js and don't know how sql injection gets handled?
My code in Node.js is something like below:

```
connection.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE firstName LIKE \'%'+firstName+'%\';', function (error, rows, fields){ someCodeHere... }
```

I receive inputs directly from user and put it inside of the query. I'm more concerned about sql injection here? Does `Node.js` do the sanitization? How to prevent sql injection in Node.js?

---

**EDIT :**
In the above link provided it's been said that we should use:

```
connection.escape(query);
```

Should I put it inside of another variable or my code should look like the below one:

```
connection.escape(query);
connection.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE firstName LIKE \'%'+firstName+'%\';', function (error, rows, fields){ someCodeHere... }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js)

Comment: @KevinReilly, plz see the edit part.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `?` placeholders which performs [escaping](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values).

```
var query = 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE firstName LIKE \'%?%\';';
connection.query(query, [firstName], function (error, rows, fields){
  //someCodeHere... 
});
```

Also, you may want to *not* set `multipleStatements` to true. It is false by default, but as noted in the readme, it is susceptible to SQL injections. Whether or not that is the case when input is escaped, I'm not sure.

> multipleStatements: Allow multiple mysql statements per query. Be careful with this, it exposes you to SQL injection attacks. (Default: false)

Comment: This code doesn't return anything! consle.log(myFetchedData) returns nothing.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I'm not in a position to test presently. Are you sure the callback is being reached at all?

Comment: By the way, unless this is used to show the emails of users with the same first name, this is likely not a safe approach query wise.

Comment: displaying emails is just for demonstration here. I show their picture and put their id inside of a hidden element.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the appropriate solution. The previous suggestion required additional [code](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#custom-format)