# Passing Object with module exports

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am still new to nodejs and Javascript, I am sorry if my question appear to be very simple but I am struggling a lot and I can't seem to find an answer on the net.

What I want to do is basically calling a script (sqlRequest.js) and send an integer while calling it. This script will send an sql request to my database and will return the result (an object) to the original file.

Here are the codes:

```
router.post('/request', function(req, res, next){
var id = req.body.id;
var essai = require('./sqlRequest.js');

console.log("INDEX: "+essai.sendSQL(id));    });
```

And now the sqlRequest.js code:

```
exports.sendSQL = function(id) {    
var mysql= require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'bcombes',
    password : 'bertrand1994',
    database : 'totalkpi'
    });
    connection.connect();
    var sql ="SELECT * FROM tra_ticket where id=?";
    var insert=[id];
    sql=mysql.format(sql, insert);

    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
            connection.end();
        }
        else {
            connection.end();
            console.log(rows);
            return rows;
        }
    });};
```

On the console I can see that the console.log("INDEX: "+essai.sendSQL(id)); appears to be undefined and is displayed before the console.log(rows).

Is it possible that the server does not wait for the function to finish and display the variable anyway ?

Anyway thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: You are triggering an Async call for the DB so you need Callback functions to wait for the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to pass a variable between files is fine. The reason your seeing `essai.sendSQL(id)` return `undefined` is because `connection.query(...)` is called asynchronously and, as you've mentioned in your question, the `console.log` fires before the DB query completes.

To fix that issue you just need to refactor your code slightly:

```
var essai = require('./sqlRequest.js');

router.post('/request', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.body.id;
    // send callback to sendSQL
    essai.sendSQL(id, function(index) {
        // this will only fire once the callback has been called
        console.log("INDEX: " + index)
    })
});
```

And then in sqlRequest.js:

```
exports.sendSQL = function (id, cb) {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'bcombes',
        password: 'bertrand1994',
        database: 'totalkpi'
    });
    connection.connect();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM tra_ticket where id=?";
    var insert = [id];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, insert);

    connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
            connection.end();
        }
        else {
            connection.end();
            console.log(rows);
            // call the callback
            cb(rows);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly, but is there a way to call it synchronously ? Why is it asynchronous ? Is there a particular reason ? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Exo no problem! :) It's asynchronous because Node.js is single threaded, so for an action like a DB request you generally wouldn't want to block the whole application from doing anything else while waiting for the DB response. That being said, there are ways of making synchronous DB requests, take a look at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32850045/4774345.