# JavaScript not waiting for the response from the endpoint

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

**Background**

This is the client side Javascript, where I make a post request to update the respective tables with the form parameters. My database has two tables-Rabbit table, and MyStuff table, and MyStuff table holds a foreign key to the rabbit table. Now, I first update the Rabbit table by making a post request which not only updates the Rabbit table but also updates the value of the **rabbitID** variable in the server, and the second request updates the MyStuff with the respective form parameters, and also makes use of the **rabbitID** variable just updated.

```
async function updateAllHelper(formDataParam) {
  let updateR = await updateRabbitTable(formDataParam);
  let updateMyS = await updateMyStable(formDataParam);
}

async function updateRabbitTable(formDataParam) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  const response = await fetch("/updateRtable", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formDataParam,
    headers
  });
  const body = await response.json();
  return body;
}

async function updateMyStable(formDataParam) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  const response = await fetch("/updateMyStable", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formDataParam,
    headers
  });
  const body = await response.json();
  return body;
}
```

Down below are my endpoints for the server side. In the "updateRtable" endpoint, I update the rabbit table and fetch the maximum rabbit ID and store that value in the **lastInsertedRId** variable. After that the "updateMyStable" endpoint updates the MyStuff table with the form parameters, and also makes use the **lastInsertedRId**.

```
app.post("/updateRtable", (req, res) => {
  console.log("went inside rabbit");
  console.log(req.body.RName);
  let successful = true;
  con.query(`INSERT INTO RABBIT(R_ID, RABBIT_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, RABBIT_STATUS, SEX, BREED) VALUES (NULL, '${req.body.RName}', '${req.body.dob}', '${req.body.rStat}', '${req.body.sex}', '${req.body.breed}')`, function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      successful = false;
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      //to get rabbitID
      console.log("went inside fetching maximum id");
      con.query(`SELECT max(R_ID) FROM RABBIT`, function(errinside, r, f) {
        if (errinside) {
          successful = false;
          console.log(errinside);
        } else {
          lastInsertedRId = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r))[0]['max(R_ID)'];
        }
      });
    }
  });
  if (successful === true) {
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true
    });

  } else {
    res.status(ERROR_STATUS_CODE).send({
      success: false
    });
  }
});

app.post("/updateMyStable", (req, res) => {
  console.log("went inside mystuff table");
  let successful = true;
  con.query(`INSERT INTO MYSTUFF(R_ID, NOTES, Kibble, Carrier, Medication, Treats, Blankets, Toys, Drop_off_Date, Pick_up_Date) VALUES ('${lastInsertedRId}', '${req.body.notes}', '${req.body.kibble}', '${req.body.carrier}', '${req.body.medic}', '${req.body.treats}', '${req.body.blankets}', '${req.body.toys}', '${req.body.dropD}', '${req.body.picKD}')`, function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      successful = false;
    }
  });
  if (successful === true) {
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true
    });
  } else {
    res.status(ERROR_STATUS_CODE).send("Server side error");
  }
});
```

**Goal**

Since the MyStuff table holds a foreign key to the Rabbit table, I obviously want to complete the call to the first endpoint completely(updating the table and fetching the latest ID), and to accomplish that goal, I am trying to make use of async/await where I wait for a response from the server side before executing the next endpoint.

**Problem**

However, the second endpoint is being executed before the completion of the first endpoint. Specifically, I found out that **lastInsertedRId** is yet to be updated while the "updateMyStable" endpoint is executed.

Comment: if(successful===false){
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true});
    }, this code in your first end-point is a typo, it should be if succesfull true then send 200 from response right?

Comment: Try using `async: false,` in your ajax call.

Comment: @Raky No, don't ever recommend that.

Comment: Get out of the habit of writing `=== false` and `=== true`. Just write `if (successful)` or `if (!successful)`.

Comment: The problem is that you're sending the response from the endpoint before the query completes. `con.query()` is asynchronous.

Comment: And that means you're checking the `successful` variable before it has been set in the callback function.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use another query to get `lastInsertedRid`. It's in `result.insertId`.

Comment: And if you do use a query, you should use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. `SELECT MAX(R_ID)` could get an ID that was inserted by another connection after your insert.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that fix, I am just going to use that idea to avoid more headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`con.query()` is asynchronous. Since it's asynchronous, it only awaits till that line and starts executing other endpoints. That's why your code is out of order.

You'll find a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850045/node-js-synchronous-queries-with-mysql).