# how to replace "?" with in a string with different array values using java/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to replace the string "?" with a different array values in the order using javascript

```
SELECT "x0"."NAME", "x0"."DOB", "x0"."SEX", "x0"."CATEGORY"
FROM "PERSON" "x0"
WHERE ((("x0"."NAME" <> ?) AND ("x0"."NAME" = ?)) AND ("x0"."NAME" < ?))
```

Comment: Is this java or javascript? And also - what exactly are you trying to achieve? From afar, it looks as though you don't really need to replace the values, but to use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Actually this is just straight up SQL. I hope he is not building a query through javascript and executes it against the db from the front end.

Comment: You are setting yourself up for a [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) unless you are super careful. Please read about this and better solutions to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js).

Comment: @Ashok, please consider marking your question as answered or editing its content to get more information! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

```
var query = 'SELECT "x0"."NAME", "x0"."DOB", "x0"."SEX", "x0"."CATEGORY"' +
                    'FROM "PERSON" "x0"' +
                    'WHERE ((("x0"."NAME" <> ?) AND ("x0"."NAME" = ?)) AND 

("x0"."NAME" < ?))';

var names = ['borr', 'odin', 'thor'];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    query = query.replace(/\?/, '"' + names[i] + '"');
}

console.log(query)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0twfrdxz/

However, this will open up your application to SQL Injection. It would probably be better to give the query named parameters and generate the statement on the server after you sanitize the inputs. That being said, the above should work for testing.

Comment: Or use [a replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).