# Using MySQL stored procedures with Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I am hoping to receive guidance on how to pass a mySQL stored procedure Javascript form data to use as parameters in a query.

I have been searching for an answer on how to use mySQL stored procedures with javascript form data as parameters.

This is what I have thus far:

```
    var first_name = req.body.firstName,
        last_name= req.body.lastName,
        email= req.body.email,
        password= req.body.password,
        gpa= req.body.gpa,
        major = req.body.major,
        classification= req.body.classification;
    var query = connection.query("CALL new_student()", function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(result);
    })
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_student`(IN first_name VARCHAR(45), 
IN last_name VARCHAR(45), IN email VARCHAR(45), IN password VARCHAR(45), IN gpa DECIMAL(3,2),
 IN major INT(10), IN classification VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password)
 VALUES (first_name, last_name, email, password);
INSERT INTO student (user_id, gpa, major, classification)
 VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),gpa, major, classification);
END
```

My intention is to take the variables, or a Javascript object that encapsulates the variables, and pass them in through "new_student()."

I am aware this may seem trivial. I am in the process of learning how to use stored procedures with Javascript.

Comment: The `new_student()` function has several parameters. You're not providing any parameters when you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide arguments to the function. If you're using the [node-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native) you can provide the parameters using syntax like a prepared statement.

```
var query = connection.query("CALL new_student(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [first_name, last_name, email, password, gpa, major, classification], 
    function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(result);
})
```

For more information about this, see [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js)

Comment: I appreciate it tons!