# Escaping query values in MySQL Query (node-mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to use node-mysql [Escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) but when I try and insert it into my MySQL query I am getting errors and can't seem to find the problem. I have tried laying out the code in different ways as well, like the one seen in github example I linked.

error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'don\\'t spam!''' at line 1
```

banReason = Don't spam!

```
var banr = con.escape(banReason)

let sql
sql = `INSERT INTO modlog (senderid, victimid, duration, releasedate, reason) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', '${user}', '${timeCode}', '${moment().add(timeValue, timeType)}', '${banr}'`
con.query(sql)
```

Comment: use prepared statements with parameters, that soves your problems and gets you secure against sql injection. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I have seen that but I didn't know how to do that in node as I believe that was for PHP? or am I getting confused (I am not a very good programmer as I just do this as a hobby)

Comment: oh sorry force of habit this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js

Comment: That's ok but that just takes me to the same GitHub page I linked in my question. I have tried the example in the node-MySQL documentation for con.escape and ? but both have given the same error that I have shown above?

Comment: you shouldn't escape, that is not what i tried to show you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779796/5193536  you see INSERT INTO posts SET ?  the vital part is the question mark.

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it working now. Sorry for not really understanding what you meant, I am new to StackOverflow so I am still getting used to how it all works.

Comment: please answer your own question and accept it, and write down what you have done, so other can find it and get also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question the correct method is to use ? that can be seen on the [node-mysql GitHub](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)
Fixed code:

```
var values = {senderid: message.author.id, victimid: user, duration: timeCode, releasedate: releaseDate, reason: banReason} 
con.query('INSERT INTO modlog SET ?', values, function(err, result) {})
```

See example from [referenced answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js/15779796#15779796)