# SQl not accepting insert query in node js throws ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'YEX8QHOG@a',
    database: 'test',
});

con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected...');
});

let createTable = 'CREATE TABLE employee(id VARCHAR(5),empname VARCHAR(30),empsal VARCHAR(30),empage VARCHAR(30))';
con.query(createTable, function (err, result, feilds) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Db Created');
    console.log(result);
});

function setData(id, empname, empsal, empage) {
    let query = `INSERT INTO employee (id,empname,empsal,empage) VALUES (${id},${empname},${empsal},${empage})`;
    con.query(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('Data insert', id);
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

async function putData() {
    let url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';
    let data = await axios.get(url);
    let dataarr = await data.data.data;
    console.log(dataarr);

    setData('1', 'Karan', '36000', '20');
    dataarr.map((emp) => {
    setData(emp.id, emp.employee_name, emp.employee_salary, emp.employee_age);
        console.log(typeof emp.id, typeof emp.employee_name, typeof emp.employee_salary, typeof emp.employee_age);
    });
}

putData();
```

> code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
> errno: 1054,
> sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Karan' in 'field list'",
> sqlState: '42S22',
> index: 0,
> sql: 'INSERT INTO employee (id,empname,empsal,empage) VALUES (1,Karan,36000,20)'

when I pass values they throw this error for employee name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using parameters, this has other benefits too (especially the prevention of SQL injection),

This is documented at: [mysql#escaping-query](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

You can change the function setData easily to do this:

```
function setData(id, empname, empsal, empage) {
    let query = `INSERT INTO employee (id,empname,empsal,empage) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`;
    let parameters = [id, empname, empsal, empage];
    con.query(query, parameters, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('Data insert', id);
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let query = `INSERT INTO employee (id,empname,empsal,empage) VALUES ('${id}','${empname}','${empsal}','${empage}')`;
```

use quotes for any kind of data '${id}'

Comment: This is very prone to SQL injections, OP should rather follow https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values.