# Unable to INSERT multiple records into MySQL database (Node.js + MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I'm trying to INSERT multiple records into a MySQL database with data gathered from the command line prompt but the data is not showing that it was stored when the SELECT * FROM script is executed.

[image: No errors after completion of the command line prompt but the MySQL result returns 0 rows]
[image: No errors after completion of the command line prompt but the MySQL result returns 0 rows]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not image.

Comment: `affectedRows: 1` means that 1 row was inserted.

Comment: please take a look at prepared staemente for node js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js

Comment: @nbk He's using that method.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it correctly according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: @Barmar The affected rows through me off because when I'm directly in MySQL workbench and run SELECT * FROM the database returns nothing. If the message says 1 row was inserted how come it's not showing the database.

Comment: I can't explain that.

Comment: check if you are connected to the right database

Comment: @nbk
Sorry for the confusion my database was properly connected and querying the data from the command line prompts. The reason I was not able to view the stored data in MySQL workbench was that I was using the wrong script execution button. Every time I ran the script the database would create itself again and delete the table contents. I was able to use the 'Execute the statement under the keyboard cursor' button with the cursor under the SELECT * FROM script. Thank you for the time and effort you both put in to help me solve this issue.

Comment: @Barmar I was able to correct the issue and view the database table in MySQL workbench.