# Pass array as value in the select query in nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to pass array as a parameter for select instead of using foreach loop. But I'm not getting any result.

```
var catIds = [];
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
   {
     catIds.push(results[i].cat_Id);
   }

SELECT * from item, item_master, category, subcategory WHERE item.masterId = item_master.Id AND item.CatId IN  (' . implode(',', $catIds) . ') and subcategory.Id =? ORDER BY item.id
```

Any alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: `implode`? Is this PHP or JS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js try prepared statements with paramaters

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT * from item, item_master, category, subcategory WHERE item.masterId = item_master.Id AND item.CatId IN  (catIds.join(',')) and subcategory.Id =? ORDER BY item.id
```