# Error in your SQL syntax: SET Syntax (Lambda function)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, node-mysql

While on the Lambda function, I'm trying to run the following query, but it throws an ER_PARSE_ERROR error.

{

"errorType": "Error",

"errorMessage": "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT A.j FROM ...' at line 1",

"trace": [

```
const vandium = require('vandium');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ multipleStatements: true });

exports.handler = vandium.generic()
    .handler((event, context, callback) => {

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'xjxj',
            user: 'xjxj',
            password: 'xjxj',
            database: 'xjxj'
        });
        var x = connection.escape(event.x);
        var y= connection.escape(event.y);
        var z = connection.escape(event.z);
  connection.query("SET @"+y+"=2; SELECT DISTINCT A.j FROM A INNER JOIN B, C WHERE A.j = B.j and C.x= " + x + " and C.y="+y+"  and C.z= " + z + "", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                connection.destroy();
                throw error;
            }
            else {
                console.log(results);
                callback(null, results);
            }
        });
    });
```

I also thought of something like:
`... "SET @y=2;..."`  but negative

I'm trying to implement something on similar lines:

```
SET @y := @k :=79;SELECT DISTINCT A.j FROM A INNER JOIN B, C WHERE A.j = B.j and C.x= " + x + " and C.y="+y+"  and C.z= " + z + "
```

Of course, there's no k in the first code block, but here's the rough idea.

What went wrong?

Comment: Why is a SQL syntax error tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: @Andreas, because this code is in javascript

Comment: please add thencomplete error message and also show the connection string

Comment: @nbk edited, please check

Comment: update your question and add  the comple sql code fo your query .. (also the code after where.....)

Comment: @user17603370 the complete sql code would help

Comment: @nbk edited, please check

Comment: the join of the tables is wrong you really should read about it, further this is qa multiquery and i can't see why yo you use a SET @id when you don't use it, but basically read about n nodejs and multi query and as last https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js which you also should read urgently

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong you are mixing implicit join based tablename separated  by comma and where condition and explicit join based on JOIN and ON clause and you are referring to a table name `something` non included  in your query..

You should use a proper, explicit join clause and use proper tablename for column

```
"SELECT DISTINCT A.j 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on A.j = B.j
INNER JOIN C ON c.X= " + x +" and c.y = " +y + " and c.z="+z+";
```

Comment: But what about `SET @id =2;` which is essential?

Comment: if your db allow multiple command  .. you can add  the SET @id =2; before the other sql command.... ..

Comment: It's not working that way, that's the problem

Comment: If you have not sql error without the SET @id =2;  .. but have error with this command ..  then you  should check if your db env allow multiple sql command..  otherwise if yuo  have error in sql you should update your question and add the complete sql code  ...not only a bief part

Comment: edited, please check

Comment: @user17603370 seems don' want understand ..  you can use the sintax  .. FROM A INNER JOIN B, C  .. you can't use JOIN and tablename separated by comma you must use or the or tablename separated  by commea and where condition  but not JOIN  Or JOIN  with the condition in the ON clause .. answer  updated ..