# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object - when trying to execute MySQL query in router

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, express-router

I have a route where I execute a few MySQL queries - the final query is a SELECT using the 'email' value from a previous query executed in the route as criteria. I have tested a few of these 'email' values using MySQL Workbench and I get results, so I'm quite sure my JS code is just wrong. Not sure if this needs to be an async/await approach but it kind of feels like it might be - I'm just not sure where to start.

Here's the error:

[image]

And the line throwing the error (330):

[image]

Here's the full code for the route:

```
// ROUND III: GETTING EVENTS AND ENROLLMENTS BY EMAIL FROM eLearningRecords TABLE; Then will need to create a SELECT query joining enrollmentrefresh and tb_elr_prereqs on emial. 
// All learndot enrollments GET route .......................................................................................................
// .................................................................................................................................
router.get("/elearning_enrollments", (err, res) => {
    // STEP 3 - DELETE EXISTING DATA FROM THE tb_elr_prereqs table ===========================================================
    // create the DELETE query and set to variable
    var sql_delete_events_and_enrollments = `DELETE FROM tb_elr_prereqs;`

    // execute the DELETE query
    pool2.query(sql_delete_events_and_enrollments, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Failed to delete records from tb_elr_prereqs!!!")
            console.log(err)
            res.sendStatus(500)
            return
        }
        console.log("Deleted the existing data from the tb_elr_prereqs table");
        // res.end()
    
    // END (STEP 3) DELETE QUERY SECTION ===========================================================================================

    // =============================================================================================================================

    // STEP 4 - GET EVENTS AND ENROLLMENTS FROM contact, enrollment, and location tables ===========================================

    // create a function
    function get_elearningrecords(){
    var sql_getemails = `SELECT email FROM enrollmentrefresh;`
    
    // execute the query
    pool.query(sql_getemails, (err, rows, results)=>{
        console.log("getting the emails from enrollmentrefresh table")
        console.log("sql_getemails" + Object.keys(rows).length)
        for(i=1;i <= Object.keys(rows).length; i++){
            if(rows[i] != undefined){
                for(var i in rows){
                    var email = JSON.stringify(rows[i].email)
                    var email = email.replace('"\\"', '')
                    var email = email.replace('\\""', '')
                    console.log(email)
                    var sql_getelr = 
                        `SELECT
                            registrationID,
                            courseName,
                            email
                        FROM
                            eLearningRecords
                        WHERE
                            email = "${email}"
                        (
                            SCORMLESSONSTATUS LIKE 'passed'
                            OR 
                            registrationstatus LIKE 'PASSED'
                        )
                        AND
                        (
                            (courseName LIKE '%Fundamentals%' AND courseName LIKE '%Part 3%')
                            OR 
                            courseName LIKE '%Creating Dashboards%'
                            OR 
                            courseName LIKE '%Advanced Searching%'
                            OR 
                            courseName LIKE '%Core Consultant Labs%'
                        );`

                    console.log(sql_getelr);
                    // execute the SELECT query
                    pool2.query(sql_getelr, (err, rows, results)=>{
                        console.log("sql_getelr" + Object.keys(rows).length)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

    get_elearningrecords();

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem lies problem leis here

```
WHERE
        email = "${email}"
    (
        SCORMLESSONSTATUS LIKE 'passed'
        OR 
        registrationstatus LIKE 'PASSED'
    )
```

this is no valid sql code.

This should be

```
WHERE
  email = "${email}"
AND
    (
        SCORMLESSONSTATUS LIKE 'passed'
        OR 
        registrationstatus LIKE 'PASSED'
    )
```

Also

```
${email}
```

this looks more like php code than javascript

Look at [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js) how to pass data in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line 294. The response from the database always come in the form of array (`rows`).

You are trying to use Object method on an Array that throws an error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. You should use Array Methods on Arrays.

Change the following lines as following:

Line 294: `console.log("sql_getemails" + rows.length)`

Line 295: `for(i=1;i <= rows.length; i++)`

Line 297: `rows.forEach(i=> {//your code goes here})`

The rest looks ok, but not good. Your code is diving into callback hell. In order to escape callback hell, I recomment using `async/await` on your functions and routes.