# How to get relation table data name instead of id

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables

**Hero**

| id | name | universe_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Mark | 1 |
| 99 | Glume | 1 |

**Universe**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Andromeda |
| 2 | Aurora |

How to return `hero` table data with universe **name** instead of **universe_id**. I'm sorry, I don't have enough experience in sql for this simple task. I read some answers in SO that need to use JOIN.

I try to do something like this.

```
exports.getHero = (req, res) => {
  
const sql = "SELECT * FROM `hero` WHERE `id`='" + req.params.id + "' JOIN `universe` WHERE `id`=`universe_id` ON `hero.universe_id`=`universe.id`";
    db.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            response.returnSingleValue(results, res);
        }
    });
};
```

But this is won't work.

UPD:

Expected result to be:

```
[{
  id: 12, 
  name: Mark,
  universe_id: Andromeda
},
{
  id: 99, 
  name: Glume,
  universe_id: Andromeda
}]
```

Comment: Your query is likely wide open to SQL injection attacks. Use your driver's mechanism for creating prepared statements/parameterized queries to mitigate this. Otherwise, it would likely be trivial to extract your entire database, make unauthorized modifications to the tables themselves, or irreversibly drop the entire database altogether.

Comment: Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint on `\`universe``.\`name\``? If not, you'll find it particularly difficult to do this via the `name` attribute if there are more than one with the same `name` value.

Comment: @esqew  I'll add authorization late.

Comment: My advice regarding your SQL injection vulnerability  has nothing to do with an authorization/authentication mechanism (at least within the scope of the question as you've put it). If your solution is to fix this "*later*", I'm not sure you're understanding the gravity of the security vulnerability you've introduced by electing to directly interpolate unsanitized user input into your query string.

Comment: @esqew Will you please send any post about this, what should I do? Which side I need to dig?

Comment: A quick Google search will yield several thousand helpful results, including [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js) which points to some helpful resources on using the driver you appear to be using in your code to create parameterized queries/prepared statements to prevent such a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const sql = "SELECT h.id, h.name, u.name as universe_id FROM `hero` as h LEFT JOIN `universe` as u ON h.universe_id=u.id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN `universe` to `hero` on the `id` value, then deliberately choose the fields in your initial `SELECT` clause which you want to see in your output:

```
SELECT `hero`.`id`, `hero`.`name`, `universe`.`name`
FROM `hero`
JOIN `universe` ON `hero`.`universe_id` = `universe`.`id`
```

Comment: I think you didn't  understand my question.I need to return hero table with universe table. And instead of universe_id show universe name from table universe. Your sql code return  universe table data with specific name

Comment: @Spectr Then you just need to be explicit with the fields in your initial `SELECT` - I've updated my answer to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Your sql code return me universe name instead of hero name. Sry. But this is not answer to my question.

Comment: "*Your sql code return me universe name instead of hero name.*" Can you elaborate further? The `name` attribute of the `hero` table is clearly in the `SELECT` expression, along with the `name` attribute of the `universe` table. It should return *both*, not one instead of the other. Can you edit your question to be explicit about what you expect a query that answers your question to return?

Comment: I updated my question. Add expected result.  Sorry for late answer

Comment: @Spectr Ok, can you elaborate on how this answer doesn't meet that specification?

Comment: Of course. It return me this -> `[{id: 12, name: 'Andromeda' }]`. This is not an expected result