# Cannot insert date into MySQL using Node.JS MySQL2

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I cannot insert a row into my MySQL table using a query in Node.JS.

Degree Table:
[image: Degree Table]

Node.JS code utilizing MySQL2:

```
await mySqlHelper
  .queryDatabaseAsync(
    "INSERT INTO Degree VALUES( id = '" +
      uuid +
      "', userId = '" +
      data.userId +
      "', degreeType = '" +
      data.degreeType +
      "', major = '" +
      data.major +
      "', yearInProgram = '" +
      data.yearInProgram +          
      "', graduationDate = '" +
      new Date(data.graduationDate).getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      (new Date(data.graduationDate).getMonth() + 1) +
      "-" +
      new Date(data.graduationDate).getDate() +
      "');"
  )
```

And the response I get is this:

```
Error: Incorrect date value: '0' for column 'graduationDate' at row 1

sql: "INSERT INTO Degree VALUES( id = '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123', userId = '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123', degreeType = 'PhD', major = 'Engineering', yearInProgram = '3', graduationDate = '2030-9-1');", 

sqlMessage: "Incorrect date value: '0' for column 'graduationDate' at row 1"
```

I've tried formatting it every way I can, and I do not know why it says it has the value '0'.

Thanks!

Comment: please add the create table also. the insert is syntactical correct and the date is accepted in mysql 8, but still to prevent **sql injection** use **prepared statements with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js

Comment: @nbk okay, I just added the MySQL table screenshot. It's a DATE column, not a DATETIME column, so I thought I could store it like that. These are two of the already entered dates: "2024-12-01", "2025-09-05"

Comment: images are not allowed see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and plese read the link with the sq injection

Comment: @PythonIsCool you have a mistake with insert syntax! Please look for my edited answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement is not valid!

The correct syntax is:
`INSERT INTO table_name(column_1,column_2,column_3) VALUES (value_1,value_2,value_3);`

Comment: it is valid https://dbfiddle.uk/bDegUN0V

Comment: This worked! I think this is what you were getting at too, @nbk. I missed it. Thank you both.