# Right Approach for preventing SQL Injection?

Tags: node.js, sql-injection

Assuming I have below code where studentId is from user input,

```
const sql  = 'select Name from student where Id = ' + studentId;
connection.exec(sql)
```

The above code is prone to SQL injection for sure. I would like to know if both of the below options address the SQL injection attacks and are the same.

**Option 1. Use a PL/SQL Variable Declaration and bind the user input with template**

```
const sql  = `DECLARE @Id=${studentId}; select Name from student where Id = @Id;`;
connection.exec(sql)
```

**Option 2. Use the parameter option provided by the library**

```
const sql  = 'select Name from student where Id = @Id;';
parameters.add({name: Id, value: studentId})
connection.exec(sql,parameters)
```

Comment: I would say option 2 is the best. In option 1 you are just using a different way to concatenate strings, but still what you are doing is string concatenation.

Comment: What librari are you using for the db?

Comment: @JorgeMontejo - https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious for connecting to MS SQL Server. The syntax I posted is just to give an overview and not exact one.

Comment: Always use prepared statements. All the major SQL drivers on npm [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) provide prepared statements as part of their library. Follow their docs and you will be secure.

Comment: @jQueeny the library that he is using provide its too, so he can still use that library instead of switching to other.

Comment: @JorgeMontejo the OP posted pseudo code and was asking more of a conceptual question. They are free to use whatever library suits their needs. If the library provides prepared statements and they use prepared statements they will be secure. Nobody said they had to switch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

The best apoach is use the function execute from the object connection, sending the Request and the params.

```
function prepareSQL() {
  const sql = `INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (@val1, @val2)`;

  const request = new Request(sql, (err, rowCount) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

  });

  // Must add parameters
  request.addParameter('val1', TYPES.Int);
  request.addParameter('val2', TYPES.Int);

  request.on('prepared', () => {
    console.log('request prepared');
    executePreparedSQL(request);
  });

  connection.prepare(request);
}

function executePreparedSQL(request) {
  connection.execute(request, { val1: 1, val2: 2 });

  request.on('requestCompleted', () => {
    console.log('DONE!');
    connection.close();
  });
}
```

You can see the example [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/4f3e2109128a5291675aba5f73a0b56aa8016d2f/examples/prepared.js#L48).

More info about the function execute in the official [documentation](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_execute).

Answer (score -1):

Consider the value of studentId to be something similar to this:

> studentId = "1; DROP TABLE some_table"

Case 1 is vulnerable to SQL Injection as it also is a form of string concatenation only. The resultant sql query in this case will be

> DECLARE @Id=1; DROP TABLE some_table; select Name from student where
> Id = @Id;

So, Case 2 is always preferred since it uses bind params